# How to fix code problem "AVADA WordPress Theme" issue with lighthouse

Tags: hyperlink, themes, lighthouse

**Lighthouse error about SEO Audit: Theme AVADA**

> Uncrawlable Link
> a

Lighthouse Uncrawlable Link:
[image]

Google Chrome Dev Tool Code View:
[image]

How to get rid of this code: `<a class="fusion-one-page-text-link fusion-page-load-link">` from My Website Avada Theme.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

../wp-content/themes/avada/footer.php
in line 60 is the code directly written. You can simply remove this line in this file.